# Compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k}(\frac{x}{n})^k$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I compute the sum $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^k$$ Its open form looks similar to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{n!} = e^x$ but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: The summation looks like $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n+1} - \left(\frac xn\right)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$
\sum _{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{k} \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^k=  \left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac xn\right)^{n+1}.
$$
Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac xn\right)^{n+1} = 0,$$
it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum _{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{k} \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^k = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n+1} = e^x.
$$

Comment: Damn, that was easier than I thought. Thank you for your answer!